# How to access a property variable of buildbot which is a dictionary?

Tags: buildbot

I have a buildbot property which I believe is a dictionary. It appears on the build page like this:

[image: Buildbot property description]

This property was set by an `extract_fn` which was returning a string converted to a dictionary.

My question is: How do I access this property as a key value pair?

For e.g.: Can I do `Property('mydictionary[\'aaa\']')` ? This doesn't seem to work. 
I need to access `mydictionary['aaa']` in a build step.

Answer (score 2):

seems a bit late but I came through a google link so maybe it will help others.

To archive passing further arguments like a key as Narayanan wants, the first way is by using the `.withArgs` function as it is describe in the [docs](https://buildbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/configuration/properties.html#renderer)

```
@util.renderer
def dictionary_value(props, key):
    mydictionary = props.getProperty('mydictionary')
    return mydictionary[key]

# pass value for key like this
f.addStep(steps.ShellCommand(command=dictionary_value.withArgs('aaa')))
```

`withArgs` accepts a `*args` or `*kwargs` argument so it is pretty flexible.

The other way would be to use a [Custom Renderables](https://buildbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/configuration/properties.html#custom-renderables) which implement the `IRenderable` interface and overwrites its `getRenderingFor` method

```
import time
from buildbot.interfaces import IRenderable
from zope.interface import implementer

@implementer(IRenderable)
class FromDict(object):
    def __init__(self, key, default = None):
      self.key = key
      self.default = default
      
    def getRenderingFor(self, props):
       return props.getPropety('mydictionary', {}).value(key, default)

# When used, the renderer must be initialized and 
# the parameters can be passed to its constructor
ShellCommand(command=['echo', FromDict(key='aaa', default='42')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Property() function takes property name as parameter.
You need [Renderer](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-properties.html#renderer) which allows to use arbitrary Python code.
For example, write renderer:

```
@util.renderer
def dictionary_value(props):
    mydictionary = props.getProperty('mydictionary')
    return mydictionary['aaa']
```

And use function name dictionary_value in any place where Property() or Interpolate() could be used.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: In the function you defined def dictionary_value(), it takes a standard argument called props. But what if I want to pass my own arguments?                 I would like to pass the key as an argument so that I can call the same function with different keys.

Comment: Narayanan, you can set key to other property:

        mydictionary = props.getProperty('mydictionary')
        mykey = props.getProperty('mykey')
        return mydictionary[mykey]